# How to check the claim name amr with Google openid?

Tags: google-oauth, google-openid

I want to check the claim name `amr` when a user use google openid. I can't see it in the JWT token. Does this claim is available?

Answer (score 0):

The **amr claim OpenID Connect** [Core Sec 2](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-modrna-authentication-1_0.html#rfc.section.5.1) [OpenID.Core] SHOULD be returned **in the id_token if a acr value** is specified in the request.

I really do not know if Google Supports this or not.